# GPU options to for gaming PC being used mostly for VR

Tags: graphics-cards, gaming, vr-headset

I"m putting together a gaming PC for a family member (to use with his Oculus Quest 2 and Oculus Link), and with the GPU shortage going on out there, I'm having a tough time. If I could find one at a reasonable price, I'd just go with a RTX 3070 and be done with it, but that is proving to be quite the difficult task. There's a good chance I'll be able to get my hands on a RTX 3060, but i've heard more than a few people refer to it as "underwhelming"... some even saying the RTX 2070 or 2060 Super would be better than the 3060 for VR. I can see that maybe being true, but what about the RTX 3060 Ti... that's got to be sufficient, no?

We're probably talking mostly Roblox VR and some Medal-of-Honor-type games... but who know what else he'll get into.

**As for the rest of the system:**

- Ryzen 7 5700
- 16GB RAM
- B550

I'd love some 1st hand intel on different setups you've used (even better if you've used the 2060 Super, 3060 or 3060 Ti for VR specifically but any knowledge is great!!) and the results you experienced if anyone cares to share. Thx!!

Answer (score 0):

For the 2070 Super vs 3060, the 2070 super is faster, but the 3060ti wins agains both. The 2060 Super is about the same speed as the 3060, but the 2060 Super can be easier to get because its older.

Source: gpu.userbenchmark.com

Comment: Do you think 1 card (or class of cards) performs better for VR specifically or is all 3D rendering the same?

Comment: This is 3d rendering, but the story would be similar in VR